# Why doesn't Voltron just stay Voltron?

Tags: anime, mecha, voltron

What's the point of the 5 lions? It seems like their enemies can never be fully defeated without them forming Voltron, so why bother fighting individually? Why not just start and end each fight as Voltron?

((This has also always bothered me about the Power Rangers as well.))

Comment: "Mechanical" - anime/manga that feature humans operating mechanical, robot-like vehicles: Voltron, Gundam, Evangelion, Patlabor, etc.

Comment: Sorry! You're right. I don't know why it accepted the "mech" tag. Shouldn't  ask/tag so soon after waking up. Edited.

Comment: [Asked and answered](http://movies.stackexchange.com/q/55402/15242) over on [movies.se].

Comment: @AnthonyGrist Thanks! I didn't think to check over there. ............... Won't let me close because duplicate isn't on the SFF Stack Exchange.

Comment: @miltonaut No need to close it, there's not really anything wrong with us covering the same ground as them.

Comment: I find it amusing that you're talking about the mecha tag but not the lack of a Voltron tag.

Comment: Questions about Star Wars have Star Wars tags... why wouldn't you have a Voltron tag?

Comment: @amaranth yeah. It's a couple of series... in fact, there's a new one that came out just this year. Got rebooted.

Comment: funny trivia: Voltron/Golion is also probably one of the first shows that features the bad guys trying to attack the 5 lions during the transformation sequence instead of just waiting and watch. If I recall correctly, they even manage to damage one of the lion (the blue? one) and for a while they have some problem because of this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Most of the time it's never addressed and it largely depends on continuity.

[According to the Voltron Wiki,](http://voltron.wikia.com/wiki/Golion) (in the Japanese series)

> Golion was once a unified robot that only sought to do battle. It one day decided to challenge a mighty space goddess. The space goddess asked why Golion could not use its abilities for good, and split it into five parts to teach it humility. Golion landed on Planet Altea and became the guardian deity of its people.

Since the original (American) Voltron: Defender of the Universe is an import of Beast King Golion and Voltron: The Third Dimension and Voltron Force are sequels that follow the same continuity,  we can assume the reasoning is similar.

In Legendary Defender, it seems like a complete reboot so the Golion tweaking off a goddess story may or may not still be true. There are, however, other options available.

Military:

One massive robot is a lot easier to find and target from space than five smaller robots.

Power consumption could be an issue. I know it was mentioned a couple of times in Voltron Force although I think it was while forming or changing configurations. Keeping the giant formed might waste resources (during a war).

Voltron can beat any monster one on one but a fleet could overwhelm it or break through and destroy whatever it's protecting. Five lions can take on more ships and offer more protection than one sword wielding target.

Plot:

The shows aren't about a robot beating monsters anymore than any of the Power Rangers series were or Captain Planet was about a blue guy stopping pollution. it's about the team and how they work together. One robot = one pilot (Big O, Gundam etc.). 5 robots = a team.

The pilots can split up and run individual missions. Plots can be a lot more interesting than monster attacks, Voltron chops it in half.

The formation sequence is a time waster. Writers have to come up with new ideas starting with monster attacks and ending with Voltron kills it. Having a couple of minutes already written for literally every episode has to be helpful. Same goes for forming the megazord on Power Rangers and summoning Captain Planet.